# Calculate Height for Image/Video based on Aspect Ratio and Width

Tags: formula, aspect-ratio

I have a width: 240
I have aspect ratio: 2.40
I need to get the height based on those two variables.  What's the formula?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Definition of the ratio:

`ratio = width / height`

Formula:

`height = width / ratio = 240 / 2.40 = 100`

Comment: And 
width = height * ratio

Comment: This answer might also be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014478/169-aspect-ratio-with-fixed-width#answer-8014510

Answer (score 11):

example of calculating 2:40 . using javascript programming language.

```
var width = 240 ;
var rat1 = 2;
var rat2 = 40;

var ratio  = width / rat1;
var calculated_height = ratio * rat2;
```

Comment: Thanks for simple and easy understanding of finding other value ..if we have one and  the ratio.. :)