# Youtube player iFrame to height and width = windows size

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

The embed I am working on needs to be having the maximum width and height of your current browser size. (so it's kinda responsive). What I now have defined is a height of 890 and a width of 1640 which obviously needs to be changed to what I want. However a simple 100% doesnt work on both. (Somehow it works for the width only)

Help is appreciated.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '890',
        width: '1640',
        playerVars:
        {       
            controls: 0,
            autoplay: 0,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            playsinline: 0,
            autohide: 0,
            listtype:'playlist',
            list:'PLDlvzhdA4-Pdv-zwkSUGr5-Bu_nn_33bP'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I gave the body a width and height of 100% and gave the height and width of the function 100% aswell, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get YouTube Video dimensions (width/height)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514635/get-youtube-video-dimensions-width-height)

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the css

```
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

This will work.