# creating a 16:9 aspect ratio iframe based on browser size (percentage)

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

how can I set a iframe size (in my case - featherlight iframe playing youtube) to be a percentage of the browser windows ?

I have a browser that may be any size, and I want to set the iframe width to be 80% of browser window..

[16:9 aspect ratio with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014478/169-aspect-ratio-with-fixed-width) mentions how to set the 16:9 height once I select a width. I don't understand how to use it.

any jsfiddle example (or codepen) will help a lot. I have tried a bunch of different ways - but the iframe does not maintain aspect ratio.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvqQgq

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YAcLViTHDOo" width="50%" class="player" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

How can I set the width to be 80% of browser window and allow height to be 16:9 ratio of the 80% of the width ?

Comment: I am not looking to fix via the other stack example. In my research that url came up

Answer (score 14):

In modern browsers you can use the `aspect-ratio` css property:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and the css:

```
iframe {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  width: 100%; /* change this to a fixed width, or create a container with a width. */
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

If you add a wrapper div you can get CSS to do the trick:

```
<div class="fluidMedia">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
<div class="fluidMedia" style="width:80%;">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work well if I reduce the width to a small number - like 20% http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVyYyq

Comment: why did you include `padding-top: 30px;`?

Comment: Without removing it, i got a black bar at the top and bottom of a 16:9 player (i guess its 30px high). Removing the `padding-top: 30px;` did remove the border. As i don't see it mentioned in the source either, i will suggest an edit

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="sixteenByNineFrame"> </iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.sixteenByNineFrame{
    width: 80%;
    height: calc(80% / (16/9));
}
```

we want width/height = 16/9
so if we have width=80.

then, height = (width / (16/9))

Comment: Consider [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364) of how and why this solves the problem. This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30194804)